# How to fix some error in external module in appcelerator studio

Tags: appcelerator, node-modules

I'm ereditated a project in Appcelerator Studio from by ex collegue. So when I try to import it in my Appcelerator Studio, I have some error from an external module.

[image]

The error in under the the module "node_modules/aws-sign2

The error is on Index.js file

[image]

This is the method with problem:

```
function canonicalizeHeaders (headers) {
  var buf = []
    , fields = Object.keys(headers)
    ;
  for (var i = 0, len = fields.length; i < len; ++i) {
    var field = fields[i]
      , val = headers[field]
      , field = field.toLowerCase()
      ;
    if (0 !== field.indexOf('x-amz')) continue
    buf.push(field + ':' + val)
  }
  return buf.sort().join('\n')
}
module.exports.canonicalizeHeaders = canonicalizeHeaders
```

The problem is on this line code:

> buf.push(field + ':' + val)

the error is: unexpeted token "."

Comment: Why do you need to create node_modules folder explicitly when everything is already available from titanium itself?

Try by deleting the node_modules folder from your app and let Titanium itself to add whatever files are required.

If you will use these module's files this way, then there can be n number of issues as these modules gets regular updates, but you won't be able to get the update and may be you will be updating them manually.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are just missing semicolon's in your javascript. 
I recently opened some old projects and a few of the files show errors that actually work(ed) fine within the apps. Try this:

```
 if (0 !== field.indexOf('x-amz')) continue;
    buf.push(field + ':' + val);
```